# search partial match in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a long Array like this:

```
var wifiArr = {
  "results": {
    "fields": [
      "Name",
      "Address",
      "Suburb",
      "Latitude",
      "Longitude"
    ],
    "rows": [
      {
        "Name": "7th Brigade Park, Chermside",
        "Address": "Delaware St",
        "Suburb": "Chermside",
        "Latitude": -27.37893,
        "Longitude": 153.04461
      },
.
. total 55 of those
.
      {
        "Name": "Annerley Library Wifi",
        "Address": "450 Ipswich Road",
        "Suburb": "Annerley, 4103",
        "Latitude": -27.50942285,
        "Longitude": 153.0333218
      },

    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to find every 'Name', 'suburb' or 'address' which contains for example 'ann' in it's name and return with the index of those items, relative to 'rows' .. Just so I can access to all details later on by using

```
var wifis = wifiArr.results.rows;

// returned index
console.log(wifis[index].Latitude);
```

I tried few different things but none of them worked as I wanted (usually they just give single index). The only thing I can use is plain Javascript and jQuery. No other libraries (as others recommended me before).

I would appreciate all the help, Thanks

Comment: This is *not* an Array, but a javascript Object (containing Arrays). Furthermore: show us what you tried?

Comment: Ok, Can I search thought that Object? or do I have to change it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you can use jQuery then you can give a try with [jQuery.grep](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/). And in your code

```
arr = jQuery.grep(wifiArr.results.rows, function(row, index) {
  return row.Name.indexOf('ann') > -1 
         || row.Address.indexOf('ann') > -1
         || row.Suburb.indexOf('ann') > -1;
});
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/ry5AC/1/

Also, if you support newer browsers, you can use **filter** function. Related [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on MDN. It is invoked with index argument ;)

Comment: cheers, It's not exactly as I wanted but I can definitely work with this :)

Comment: If you need index, of course you can use jQuery.inArray function. I've just updated the fiddle.